# How to implement connection pooling for a python application connecting to Vertica or PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, connection-pooling, vertica

I have a python application which interacts with vertica database through vertica python client. Currently there is no connection pool to manage the connections, instead for every request a new connection is opened and then closed at the end of the request. However, this design will cost to handle concurrent requests. Also, the python application is run on a uwsgi and an Nginx server to process multiple requests.

I would like to use an existing connection pool to handle connections to vertica from python but I dont seem to find connection pools like C3Po or Hikari in python. Could you please help me with the pools for python - vertica

Comment: Take a look at `sqlalchemy` module. References:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html
https://github.com/jamescasbon/vertica-sqlalchemy

Comment: Were you able to confirm if connection pooling is supported for Vertica Python, See example link for ADO.NET https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientADO/ADO.NETConnectionProperties.htm

Answer (score 0):

For native Postgres, have a look at some of the connection pools discussed at [Should PostgreSQL connections be pooled in a Python web app, or create a new connection per request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889104/should-postgresql-connections-be-pooled-in-a-python-web-app-or-create-a-new-con)

For Vertica, it doesn't look like connection pooling is available in the native driver though it might be worth posting an issue on GitHub if you'd like more specific details.  You could probably use Vertica's ODBC driver through pyODBC since that supports connedction pooling if configured as discussed at http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/conn_pool.html